# Mongoose and MongoDB - Get all countries and users associated with country

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, aggregation-framework

So I have a list of posts data that looks like this:

```
[
  {user: 'Bob', country: 'USA'}
  {user: 'Kim', country: 'Mexico'}
  {user: 'Darren', country: 'Mexico'}
  {user: 'Joe', country: 'Mexico'}
]
```

I want to get my data like:

```
[{Mexico: {'Kim', 'Darren', 'Joe'}, USA: {'Bob'}}]
```

This is what I got so far but I'm a bit confused by the docs and the posts here are pretty outdated. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Post.aggregate([
  { $group: { _id: "$country", users: { $in: "$posts" } } },
]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost to the answer. You need [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) `user` field to `users`.

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  $group: {
    _id: "$country",
    users: {
      $push: "$user"
    }
  }
})
```

[Sample Mongo Playground (`$push`)](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sAGrfLGMCeX)

---

Use [`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) to add value to array without duplicate.

> The $addToSet operator adds a value to an array unless the value is already present, in which case $addToSet does nothing to that array.

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  $group: {
    _id: "$country",
    users: {
      $addToSet: "$user"
    }
  }
})
```

[Sample Mongo Playground (`$addToSet`)](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8fUSoMwqcbD)

Comment: thanks a bunch. the $in was confusing as hell lol.

Answer (score 2):

`$group` `$addToSet`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$country",
      "users": {
        "$addToSet": "$user"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

result

```
[
  {
    "_id": "Mexico",
    "users": [
      "Kim",
      "Darren",
      "Joe",
      "Bob"
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "USA",
    "users": [
      "Bob"
    ]
  }
]
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MKuyO7oLV3F)

Comment: just to add a bit more complexity to it, is there a way i can remove duplicate user. So if Bobs been to Mexico twice, i still just want him to show up once. I know theres a distinct() but i dont think it works with aggregate

Comment: i update my answer, use `addTosSet`

Comment: God bless your kind soul!